# `CountedSet` initialization issue

Tags: ios, swift, nsset, swift3, nscountedset

I'm comparing the characters contained within two words. In seeking to accomplish this, `Set` (aka `NSSet`) seemed like the way to go to accomplish this task. I've discovered it returns false positives on matches, so I am attempting to use `CountedSet` (aka `NSCountedSet`) instead.

I'm able to initialize a `Set` without issue, but I can't get the `CountedSet` initializer to work. Here's what I've done...

I start with a `String`:

```
// Let's say myTextField.text = "test"
let textFieldCharacters = myTextField.text?.characters
// word is a string from the ENABLE list of words
let wordCharacters = word.characters
```

Then I dump the characters into an `Array`:

```
var wordCharactersArray = [Character]()
for character in wordCharacters {
    wordCharacterArray.append(character)
}


var textFieldCharactersArray = [Character]()    
for character in textFieldCharacters {
    wordCharacterArray.append(character)
}
```

Then I create a `Set` from the character arrays:

```
let textFieldSet = Set<Character>(textFieldCharactersArray)
let wordSet = Set<Character>(wordCharactersArray)
```

Finally, I test to see if the `textFieldSet` is a superSet of `wordSet` with the following:

```
textFieldSet.isSuperset(of: wordSet)
```

Going back to my example, if `myTextField.text` is "test", I'm returning values for `word` whose characters are a superset of the `wordSet`, but the counts of the individual elements don't match the character counts of `myTextField.text`

In researching my issue, I've found `CountedSet` (fka `NSCountedSet`), which I think would resolve my issue. It has two method signatures:

```
public convenience init(array: [AnyObject])
public convenience init(set: Set<NSObject>)
```

I've tried initializing the 2 sets of characters like so:

```
let textFieldSet = CountedSet(array: textFieldCharacterArray)
let wordSet = CountedSet(array: wordCharacterArray)
```

I get the following error for the sets

> Cannot convert value of type '[Character]' to expected argument type
>   '[AnyObject]'.

So I tried initializing the set like this:

```
let textFieldSet = CountedSet(array: textFieldCharacterArray as! [AnyObject])
```

Which yields the following error:

> 'AnyObject' is not a subtype of 'Character'

I've also tried to initialize the `CountedSet` with a `Set`, per the method signature, but I get errors when I try to do that, too.

Any suggestions how to initialize a `CountedSet` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick workaround idea: use String instead of Character? for example, `let textFieldCharacters = "test".characters.map { String($0) }; let textFieldSet = CountedSet(array: textFieldCharacters)` should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was a key to 1) getting me on the right path and 2) trimming my code down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that if you need to compare not just the presents of elements but also their count, you should use `CountedSet`, which is a renaming of `NSCountedSet` for swift 3.0. The problem you are running into is `CountedSet` can only accept elements that are objects and `Characters` are not. As Eric D points out in their comment, the easies way to get around this is by mapping your `[Character]` to `[String]` which will bridge to `[NSString]`.

You are not running into this problem using `Set`, because it is a native Swift collection type that initialize with elements of any type. This is why you can initialize a `Set` with `[Character]`.

To see the difference:

```
let word = "helo"
let wordCharacters = Array(word.characters)
let wordSet = Set(wordCharacters)
let wordCharStrings = wordCharacters.map{String($0)}
let wordCountedSet = CountedSet(array: wordCharStrings)

let textField = "hello"
let textFieldCharacters = Array(textField.characters)
let textSet = Set(textFieldCharacters)
let textFieldCharStrings = textFieldCharacters.map{String($0)}
let textFieldCountedSet = CountedSet(array: textFieldCharStrings)

textFieldCountedSet.isSubset(of: wordCountedSet as! Set<NSObject>) // returns false, but if word had two or more l's it would return true
textSet.isSubset(of: wordSet) // returns true
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got a compiler error on this line `wordCountedSet.isSubset(of: textFieldCountedSet as Set`. I changed `as` to `as!` and got it working with this warning: "Cast from 'CountedSet' to unrelated type 'Set<NSObject>' always fails". I ran the code and it worked despite the warning.